# How to hook class instance method with detours?

Tags: winapi, dll, hook, dll-injection, detours

I've been trying to hook the `GetSelectedItems` function inside `Shobjdl_core.h`

```c
 virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSelectedItems( 
            /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IShellItemArray **ppsai) = 0;
```

Since it is a virtual function, I cannot compile the code.

```c
HRESULT(WINAPI* TrueSleep)(IShellItemArray** ppsai) = GetSelectedItems;

// Detour function that replaces the Sleep API.
//
HRESULT WINAPI TimedSleep(IShellItemArray** ppsai)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> Error C2065 'GetSelectedItems': undeclared identifier DllCreateFile

Is there an example for hooking of class instance methods?

[Only link](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/Using-Detours) is this one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
HRESULT(WINAPI IFileOpenDialog::* TrueSleep)(IShellItemArray** ppsai) = &IFileOpenDialog::GetSelectedItems;



HRESULT WINAPI TimedSleep(IShellItemArray** ppsai)
{
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Um, this detours the thunk, not the actual function. The actual function isn't known until runtime since it is virtual.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/tree/main/samples/commem do you think this will solve it?

Comment: If you have to ask, you should not hit the *"Post Your Answer"* button.